# Security updates for old WSO2 ESB versions

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-esb

My organisation has a program running on WSO2 ESB 4.5.1. This is running on the very old Tomcat 7.0.28 for which there have been numerous updates since its release.

The [Security Patches page](http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/enterprise-service-bus) on the WSO2 website only lists patches for versions 4.8+. Is there a way I can obtain older security patches or otherwise update Tomcat?

(I've tried to install a newer version of WSO2, but have been unable to get the application running.)

Comment: Tomcat is used for admin console, if I am not mistaken. You can hide admin area behind nginx or apache httpd. Services are using axis transort and don't deal with tomcat.

Comment: If I cause an exception in the JSP it comes up with a Tomcat error page though - I thought it was all bundled up together?

Comment: JSP errors it is errors on admin console, it has nothing to do with services.

Comment: You can make ssh tunnel to wso_host:9443/carbon and have access to admin console. Proxy services use different ports, and tomcat use different library according to http://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP-NIO+Transport  and based i have seen in sources

Comment: It is apache http core lib http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga